# Where is Android execution jar file?(Just out of curiosity)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am developing an android application  **Api level 8.**

Now I would like to know about where is the **actual jar** (not the 'android.jar' Api jar included in the project) file that contains the execution body, *i.e The implementation jar file of 'android.jar*.

I searched a lot through the android sdk installation directory but no such jar file was found. Does any jar file exist for this purpose? If not, then how does the android virtual device execute the source code?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://androidforums.com/application-development/1045-source-code-android-jar.html

Answer (score 5):

you can find the platforms android.jar file here, `..\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-15`.

The platforms jar is different from the emulators jar as the later contains the hidden & internal API as well.

If you want the **implementation class files**, you will have to pull the jar file from the **emulator** of that platform.

In higher API levels you might also have to de-compile dex or odex files to class files.

More information [here](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/).

I hope this will help..

Answer (score 4):

The jar files and the class files are never needed .Your code when converted to apk is not converted into different classes and jars but apks.If open you see apk file (they are just zip files) you will see no jars and classes .they are converted to dex files. Remember Android does not uses JVM but uses DVM thats optimized of Moblie use.(If i have understood what you want)

Comment: Thanks Vincent for reply, but by question still exist. for example where is the body implementation of objTextview.text("").

Comment: @Vincent, it would be incorrect to say _the class files are never needed_ because the dx converts these .class files to the dex format

Comment: that is true but in android device there is no need for class.

Comment: @SreejithG : I am sorry i didnt get what you mean by ..."body implementation of objTextview.text("")"...

Comment: @Vincent, ie I create an object of Textview Component in my activity class,the I call the setText() function (in the above comment I miss the 'set' portion) , now the statement is like this objTextView.setText("Hello world"); Now I run the program, then where is the actual function receiving the "Hello world" Text as its input parameter.